# How to use show function with 2 values

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve the problem on HackerRank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/breaking-best-and-worst-records/problem

What the question ask is to display 2 values no of times the record is broken for min score and highest score

I have wrote the algorithm to find it. I am stuck with how to output 2 values.

Following is my solution. Currently it display's the number of highest record broken. I want to show 2 values so that it passes the test in hackerrank.

```hs
mxscore::(a,a,a,a) -> a
mxscore (_,a,_,_) = a
mnscore::(a,a,a,a) -> a
mnscore (a,_,_,_) = a
lscore :: (a, a,a,a) -> a
lscore (_,_,a,_) = a
hscore :: (a, a,a,a) -> a
hscore (_,_,_,a) = a


main = interact $ show . hscore .solve . map read . tail . words 


solve::[Int] -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
solve (x:xs) =  solve1 x xs
    where solve1 d dx = foldl(\acc x -> if x > mxscore acc 
                        then (mnscore acc, x, lscore acc, hscore acc + 1) 
                        else if x < mnscore acc then (x, mxscore acc, lscore acc  + 1, hscore acc) else acc ) (d,d,0,0) dx
```

Current solution works as follows

```
*Main> solve [10, 5, 20, 20, 4, 5, 2, 25, 1]

(1,25,4,2)
```

where 4 is number of time lowest record is broken
and 2 is number of time highest record is broken

```
*Main> solve [3, 4, 21, 36, 10, 28, 35, 5, 24, 42]

(3,42,0,4)
```

where 0 is number of time lowest record is broken
and 4 is number of times highest record is broken

The first number is no. of scores 
The second line is Score

Input:

9

10 5 20 20 4 5 2 25 1

Output :

2 4

Ans. explanation 2 is the number of time the records were broken for highest score
4 is the number of time the records were broken of lowest score

Comment: Your  `solve`  function looks correct to me (although it would be more concise and easier to read if you used pattern matching on the 4-tuple `acc`). Can you explain what's not working about it? Is there a particular test case it fails on?

Comment: I want to display last and second last values of tuple. for example 4 & 2. Currently I am able to show just the highest value using show

Comment: Can you please give a clear description of what the inputs and outputs should be. I confess I missed your definition of `main` and just treated your `solve` examples as showing what should happen. Please show us what the inputs to `main` should be and what the corresponding output would be.

Comment: Updated the Question at the bottom of the question I have provided the Input and Output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the question. I created 1 more function that would override the show

```
mxscore::(a,a,a,a) -> a
mxscore (_,a,_,_) = a
mnscore::(a,a,a,a) -> a
mnscore (a,_,_,_) = a
lscore :: (a, a,a,a) -> a
lscore (_,_,a,_) = a
hscore :: (a, a,a,a) -> a
hscore (_,_,_,a) = a


main = interact $ show1  .solve . map read . tail . words 

show1::(Int, Int, Int, Int) -> String
show1 (_,_,a,b) = show b ++ " " ++ show a


solve::[Int] -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
solve (x:xs) =  solve1 x xs
    where solve1 d dx = foldl(\acc x -> if x > mxscore acc 
                        then (mnscore acc, x, lscore acc, hscore acc + 1) 
                        else if x < mnscore acc then (x, mxscore acc, lscore acc  + 1, hscore acc) else acc ) (d,d,0,0) dx
```

Thanks